# Can this return or set variable code be made simpler?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can this be simplified to a single one-liner, without the one liner being more difficult to read?

```
if self.is_running:
    return

self.is_running = True
```

Something like:

```
return if self.is_running else self.is_running = True
```

*(Obviously the above won't work, just an example of what i'm looking to achieve)*

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I think you cant return and not return in the same line, thats point of return

Comment: You could put the `return` on the same line as the `if` statement: `if self.is_running: return`. But that's as far as you can reduce the LOC here I think.

Comment: Was just a thought really, but your explanation makes sense. Should I delete the question or wait for someone to answer so no one else asks such a stupid question in future? :P

Comment: @Plopp that's simply incorrect. You can't use assignments in a conditional expression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: Oo true, my bad, I overlooked that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve with `return if self.is_running else self.is_running = True` is called a conditional expression. However, you cannot use any kind of statement (eg. `self.is_running = True`) in a conditional expression. A conditional expression should take the form:

```
a if condition else b
```

where `b` is a *value* not a statement.

In your case, the shortest code you can achieve is something like:

```
if self.is_running: return
self.is_running = True
```